# Why Google doesn't recognise "chatgpt" as a searchable term?

Tags: google-search, search

Google must be well aware of "ChatGPT" developed by OpenAI by now after [issuing a code red](https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/chatgpt-caused-code-red-at-google-report-says/).

However when I made a below simple search, it offered an auto correction as "chatbot" in place of "ChatGPT". Is it possible that Google isn't aware of this AI in its popular form?

[image]

---

Even the autocomplete also doesn't offer any [positive] searching sentences related to "ChatGPT". However it very well auto completes search related to "Bard" !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of the question reflected in the title is wrong

> Google doesn't recognize ChatGPT as a searcheable term.

The screenshot shows a page result showing on top of the search results

> Did you mean: why chatbot is so smart

"Did you mean" is shown when the Google index doesn't have enough indexed content based on the Google search algorithm. This means that there are no many content about "why chatgpt is so smart".

Below the "Did you mean" widget, there is a [featured snippet](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9351707?hl=en). This shows that Google found a *keyword* that is likely to be the most important "searcheable term".

Note: The use of the term *keyword* and *searcheable term* might be obsolete considering that the first example of [How to search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en) article use a phrase.

Please bear in mind that results shown to each user might vary depending on multiple factors, moment (day and time), location, previous searches based on the browser history, etc. To learn about this, please read [Personalization & Google Search results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/12410098?hl=en).

By the way, when I search "why chatgpt is so smart" I don't get "Did you mean".